# Using let in an if statement in Swift

Tags: if-statement, swift

The keyword `let` is used to define constants in Swift. But I keep finding `let` being used in `if` statements, and Ive been wondering why this is, or at least what the advantage to this is.

For example in this code:

```
if !session.setActive(false, error: &error) {
    println("session.setActive fail")
    if let e = error {
        println(e.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
}
```

Why is `error` tested with a `let` in this statement: `if let e = error` ?

I understand why `error` needs testing, so we can make sure we can get at `.localizedDesciption` but I don't understand why we cant just do something like:

```
    if error {
        println(error.localizedDescription)
```

Outside of this example Ive also noticed `let` being used in a lot of other `if` statements. What are the advantages to this? I would love to know the thinking behind it.

Finally, can `var` be used in an `if` statement in the same way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process is called **optional binding**. You use it to check whether the optional (`error` in your case) contains a value, and if yes, to assign that value to the bound constant (`e` in your case).

You may also use `var` instead of `let` to bind the value to a variable rather than a constant:

```
if var error = error {
    // Do something with error
    println(error.localizedDescription)
    return
}
```

Note that I used the same name (`error`) in the snippet above. Within the `if` block, `error` is no longer of an optional type.

Comment: Suggested reading: [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_503)

Comment: I think OP's issue is that we already have a perfectly good variable (`error`), so why rebind it as `e`...

Comment: Indeed, why do `if let e=error` when we could do `if error!` ? What makes `let e=error` safer than `error!` when tested inside an if statement?

Comment: @Jimmery If you do `error!` and the optional doesn't have a value, a runtime error will occur. That's exactly what we're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use the same name:

```
 if let error = error {
     println(error.localizedDescription)
     return
 }
```